# Divide batch of polygons inside shapefile into aligned grid using ArcGIS 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, polygon-creation

[image]I have a polygon shapefile that contain a batch of rectangular polygons with almost equal dimensions. These polygons are not touching each other, they are on some distance. Now I want to split or divide each polygon in 6x6 small rectangular grid. All newly created polygons should be aligned by horizontal and vertical direction. I have tried fishnet tool but that gives me the grid of whole extent that doesn't match with my polygons. Also,  I have tried parcel fabric, but that works just for separated polygons,  not for a batch process. I want to do this using ArcGIS 10.4.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or drawing of what you want?

Comment: I have updated the question with a screenshot. I want to create new rectangular polygons inside each of these, so they should be aligned with horizontal and vertical lines (that should not be like bricks in the wall). Each polygon from the screenshot should be divided in 6x6 new smaller polygons. Ignore these small gaps.

Comment: Replace nrows, ncols = 1,8 by nrows,ncols = 6,6

Comment: Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but might work:

[image] 1. Split by attributes to get one feature class for each rectangle. I first had to add a new field and calculate using OID to get a field to split by. Output to an empty file geodatabase (test.gdb in my example)
 2. Iterate over each split fc and create a fishnet using iterate output as template:

[image]

3. Merge the fishnets and Intersect with original fc:
   [image]